# How do I go through every element in a LinkedList like in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

For LinkedList objects, how do I go through every element of the LinkedList?

I know in arrays I can do for(int x: array), but how can I do this exact thing for LinkedList objects?

Comment: The point of the new style for loop, the one you show in your question, is that it works for both arrays and collections, or to be more precise, anything that implements java.lang.Iterable

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the enhanced for style to iterate over a linked list.  You'll be iterating over every object in it, though.

Answer (score 0):

The exact same way:

```
for (Something s: SomethingList) {
    // do something with s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can create a reference for your linked list. `LinkedList ll = YourLinkedList;`
Then you can do `while (ll != null) ll = ll.next;`.

Comment: No... You're thinking of an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Since both are collections, you can iterate them in the same way.
Here ( [For Each Loop Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)) are explained the different usages.